# binary search but it doesn't search the upper part of the object list

Tags: python, binary-search

Im trying to create a code that searches an item from an object list, but it only checks the lower part of the list. If i try to search for the items in the lower part of the list, it gives good output, but when I try the higher part, it doesn't do the job.

code:

```
def searching(alist):
    param = input("\nWhat are you looking for? ")
    param = param.title()
    
    if binary(param, alist):
        print("\nHere are the results of your search")
        if param == 'Electric Guitar':
            results = [obj for obj in alist if obj.type == param]
            results = bubble(results)
        if param == 'Bass Guitar':
            results = [obj for obj in alist if obj.type == param]
            results = bubble(results)
        if param == 'Acoustic Guitar':
            results = [obj for obj in alist if obj.type == param]
            results = bubble(results)
        if param == 'Accessory':
            results = [obj for obj in alist if obj.type == param]
            results = bubble(results)#Modify this such that the covered indexes will be of the same type
            
        view_inv(results)
    else:
        print("\nSorry, we don't have the item that you are looking for.")
        main()

def binary(word, sett):
    first = 0
    last = len(sett) - 1
    asd = False
    global paramm
    while first<=last and not asd: 
        mid = (first + last)//2
        if sett[mid].eq(word):
            return True
            asd = True
        else:
            if sett[mid].gt(word):
                last = mid - 1
            else:
                first = mid + 1
def bubble(collection):
    my_list = list(collection)
    for endnum in range(len(my_list)-1, 0, -1):
        for i in range(endnum):
            if my_list[i].__gt__(my_list[i+1]): #the one to check the different types of variable and compare
                my_list[i], my_list[i+1] = my_list[i+1], my_list[i]
    return my_list
```

class:

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, hproduct, htype, hprice, havail):
        self.name = hproduct
        self.type = htype
        self.price = hprice
        self.avail = havail
    def view(self):
        print(self.name.ljust(35), self.type.ljust(28), str(self.price).ljust(8), self.avail)
    def __lt__(self,other):
        if type(other) is str:
            return self.type < other
        else:
            if param == 'name':
                return self.name < other.name
            if param == 'price':
                return self.price < other.price
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.name == other.name
    def __gt__(self,other):
         return self.price > other.price
    def eq(self,other):
        return self.type == other
    def gt(self,other):
        return self.type > other
    def lt(self,other):
        return self.type < other

item_001 = Product('Tyma TD-10E Dreadnought', 'Acoustic Guitar', 23450, 'In Stock')
item_002 = Product('Baton Rouge AR21C/ME Traveler', 'Acoustic Guitar', 14900, 'In Stock')
item_003 = Product('Phoebus Baby 30 GS Mini', 'Acoustic Guitar', 6900, 'In Stock')
item_004 = Product('Maestro Project X X1-V1 OM', 'Acoustic Guitar', 32500, 'In Stock')
item_005 = Product('Sire A4 Grand Auditorium', 'Acoustic Guitar', 27490, 'In Stock')

item_006 = Product('Tagima TW55', 'Electric Guitar', 9500, 'In Stock')
item_007 = Product('Epiphone G400 ', 'Electric Guitar', 19500, 'In Stock')
item_008 = Product('D’Angelico Premiere DC', 'Electric Guitar', 49000, 'In Stock')
item_009 = Product('PRS Silver Sky', 'Electric Guitar', 138950, 'In Stock')
item_010 = Product('Vintage V100 Reissued', 'Electric Guitar', 27950, 'In Stock')

item_011 = Product('Phoebus Buddie 30 GS-E', 'Bass Guitar', 8720, 'In Stock')
item_012 = Product('Sire U5', 'Bass Guitar', 27490, 'In Stock')
item_013 = Product('Lakland Skyline Vintage J', 'Bass Guitar', 82950, 'In Stock')
item_014 = Product('Schecter Model T Session 5', 'Bass Guitar', 45900, 'In Stock')
item_015 = Product('Tagima Millenium Coda 4', 'Bass Guitar', 14900, 'In Stock')

item_016 = Product('Boss Katana 50 Mk II ', 'Accessory', 15950, 'In Stock')
item_017 = Product('TC Electronic BH250 Micro Bass', 'Accessory', 18990, 'In Stock')
item_018 = Product('Kemper Profiler Powerhead', 'Accessory', 130000, 'In Stock')
item_019 = Product('Headrush Pedal Board', 'Accessory', 27490, 'In Stock')
item_020 = Product('NUX MG30', 'Accessory', 12900, 'In Stock')

inventory = [item_001, item_002, item_003, item_004, item_005, item_006, item_007, item_008, item_009, item_010, item_011, item_012, item_013, item_014, item_015, item_016, item_017, item_018, item_019, item_020]
```

desired output:

```
Phoebus Buddie 30 GS-E              Bass Guitar                  8720     In Stock
Tagima Millenium Coda 4             Bass Guitar                  14900    In Stock
Sire U5                             Bass Guitar                  27490    In Stock
Schecter Model T Session 5          Bass Guitar                  45900    In Stock
Lakland Skyline Vintage J           Bass Guitar                  82950    In Stock
```

output:

```
Sorry, we don't have the item that you are looking for.
```

Any help will really do.

Comment: Could you provide the code for the method `bubble`, please?

Comment: You have not posted the full code for the binary() function. Also, in that function after returning true, setting `asd` to true will not execute.

Comment: i added it @rajah9,

Comment: and that is the complete code of the binary() @Anand Sowmithiran

Comment: If you can't come up with a better name than "asd" for a variable, you can be pretty sure that you don't know what its purpose is. What *is* its purpose? You're returning before assigning it a new value...

Comment: It is very confusing that you have two different equalities, two different "greater than", different "less than"s, where one of them *depends on the state of a global variable*, and `a < b` is not necessarily equivalent to `b > a`. Also, the entire point of the "magic operator methods" is that you can write `a > b` instead of `a.__gt__(b)`.

Comment: Doing a binary search and then traversing the entire list to collect all the matching elements kind of defeats the point of searching. Also, you have four identical conditionals. Replacing that whole "search and gather code" with `results = [obj for obj in alist if obj.type == param]; if len(results) ==0: print "Sorry"; else: view_inv(bubble(results))` would be more efficient and a fair bit shorter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `inventory` is not ordered by the `type`, which is what your search is looking for - your first `sett[mid].type` is `'Electric Guitar'`, so you never look to its right.

Comment: what do you think I should do?

Comment: You need to order the list by the key you want to search for, either by sorting it or by defining it in the appropriate order.